# Creating Multiple OnClick jQuery Animate events with a single ID and next/sibling event

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey Everyone - I'm trying to get a .toggle event to fire when my user clicks on an id with "click-toggle".. I can't figure out why this isnt working. This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#click-toggle').click(function() {
var clicked = $(this);
$(clicked).parent().parent().next().toggle('blind',400); return false;}); });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="schedule-day-entry">
 <div class="schedule-day-time"><p>10:00<reg>am</reg></p></div>
 <div class="schedule-day-description"><p><a href="#" id="click-toggle">Title</a></p>
 </div>
 <div class="schedule-day-more-info"><p>Description</p></div>
</div>

<div class="schedule-day-entry">
  <div class="schedule-day-time"><p>10:00<reg>am</reg></p></div>
  <div class="schedule-day-description"><p><a href="#" id="click-toggle">Title</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="schedule-day-more-info"><p>Description</p></div>
</div> 

</body></html>
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What element is supposed to toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate id attributes on a single webpage. id="click-toggle"
I changed those to classes. Also, try the .toggle('blind') without the second argument. That seemed to work for me. There is also a good slideToggle() jquery function. You did remember to  attach the jquery file didn't you?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

Comment: Hey Rubicksman, changing the a element classes did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Don't forget to click the green check to accept your favorite answer!